# JavaScript: access table ID in AJAX callback URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table where I dynamically generate table identificator in `data-controller-name`. This is how it looks in my page source:

```
<table data-controller-name="campaigns_index" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"
  data-source="/en/campaigns.json">
```

Then in JavaScript I'd like to access that `data-controller-name` value, e.g., `campaigns_index` in generating URL:

```
"stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
    $.ajax( {
      "url": "/datatables_states/[data-controller-name].json",
      "data": data,
      "dataType": "json",
      "type": "PATCH",
      "success": function () {}
    } );
  }
```

I need this for [Datatables stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback).

So far it's not working as URL is passed as is without changing to `campaigns_index.json` **How do I make it work, please?** I assume I have to have some variable there which then can be used for generating url correctly. Thank you!

Comment: most likely the settings function will have the selector for the table, if not use jquery to get the attribute assuming you have only one datatable on the page

Comment: how about using "$(table).attr('data-controller-name')" to get the value, and use the value in url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your table an id:

```
<table id="camptable" data-controller-name="campaigns_index" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"
  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%"
  data-source="/en/campaigns.json">
```

Then ajax will look like:

```
var camp = $("#camptable").attr('data-controller-name');
"stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
$.ajax( {
  "url": "/datatables_states/"+camp+".json",
  "data": data,
  "dataType": "json",
  "type": "PATCH",
  "success": function () {}
} );
```

}